# Draw a line at a canvas

Tags: line

Currently I have this code:

```
sample.beginPath();
sample.moveTo(X1.x,Y1.x );
sample.lineTo(X2.x,Y2.y);
sample.stroke();

sample.beginPath();
sample.arc(X2.x, Y2.y, 4, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
sample.fill();
sample.lineWidth = 1;
sample.stroke();
```

This will create this :

[image]

This will point in any direction.

What I want is this:

[image]

Note:

```
1.There will only be one line, either Line A or B.

2.They will always point from left to right.

3. They are in 45 degrees.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the following figure:

[image]

Point **(x1,y1)** is the starting point of the mouse. Assuming that mouse has moved to the **right** (you'll have to handle the case when it moves left), new mouse coordinates will be **(x2,y2).** However, we don't want to draw the line between (x1,y1) and (x2,y2), because the slop of this line (the angle) won't be the desired one. So we must calculate the coordinates of the new point **P**, that stands on our line. **Note:** I assumed that x-coordinate of this point will be equal to new mouse-x coordinate x2!

With this assumption and with help of some basic 2D geometry we get:

```
a = x2 - x1
tan(alpha) = b / a => b = a * tan(alpha)
P.x = x2
```

Value of the P.y coordinate depends on whether mouse has moved **up** or **down** from the start position.

```
IF (y1 > y2)
    P.y = y1 - b // Mouse has moved up (drawing shows this scenario)
ELSE
    P.y = y1 + b // Mouse has moved down (not shown in the drawing)
```

So we have a new point P, and now you can simply draw the line between (x1,y1) and P. You also have to handle some special case such as what if mouse moves to the left of starting point.

In order to get your point P, you should plug-in your desired angle as well (it can be different than 45 degrees, but it has to be a **positive angle** - you could derive formula that will work fine with negative angles as well).